# AppBarLayout autocomplete Expand/collapse when user stop scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to autocomplete scrolling to top/bottom when user stop scrolling. like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJkwP.png).
I have tested OnOffsetChangedListener but always something is wrong.
Any idea please.

There is no java code used for this action.

this is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?attr/backLayout"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <!--app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed" -->
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        ...no toolbar

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/collLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            >

            ...content
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        ...content
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

here some flags to check the scrolling:

```
int TO_UP = -1;
int TO_DOWN = +1;
boolean AutoScroll = false;
```

check on touch if user released and check the flag to auto-scroll to top:

```
nsv_scroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

  if(AutoScroll){
    gotoTop();
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
});
```

check if user is scrolling to top also be able to scroll to top and set flag to true , else false and no autoscroll:

```
    nsv_scroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        Log.e("Scroll", scrollY + "");
        if (scrollY > 0) {
            if (nsv_scroll.canScrollVertically(TO_UP))
                AutoScroll = true;
        } else {
            AutoScroll = false;
        }
    }
});
```

simply go to top:

```
void gotoTop(){
    nsv_scroll.fling(0);
    nsv_scroll.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
}
```